# Store float as bytes into large array instead of new byte[]

Tags: c#, file, serialization

I need to serialize a bunch of `float`s and convert to little endian if necessary.  I'm aware of `BitConverter.GetBytes(float)`, but I'd rather avoid allocating a ton of little 4-byte arrays on the GC heap.  How can I do the conversion into an existing large `byte[]` array with an offset index?  I want something like:

```
float[] theFloats; // filled up somewhere
byte[] theBytes = new byte[theFloats.Length * 4];

int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numFloats; ++i)
{
    MagicClass.CopyFloatToBytes(theFloats[i], theBytes, offset);
    offset += 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `MemoryStream` around the array, then create a `BinaryWriter` and write floats to it.

Comment: This looks promising.  Any way to set which endian-ness the writer uses?

Comment: @japreiss: Not that I know of.  IIRC, Jon Skeet & Marc Gravel's MiscUtils library has an endian-aware version.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [BitConverter.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwsaf3w.aspx)?

You can also do this with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Convert32BitType
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Int32Value;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float FloatValue;
}

// Example:
var tmp = new Convert32BitType();
tmp.FloatValue = 1.1;
int ival = tmp.Int32Value;
byte b1 = (byte)(ival >> 24);
byte b2 = (byte)(ival >> 16);
byte b3 = (byte)(ival >> 8);
byte b4 = (byte)(ival >> 0);
```

Another possibility is to used the `fixed` keyword and cast the pointer, but that requires unsafe code.